# Merge HTML files into one without using JSoup?

Tags: java, html, swt

I am looking to merge HTML files into one using java as i have to show combined file in SWT browser. is there any way?
HTML frames were an option, but they divide the browser into different sections.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option, but it is not a very good solution.

You can use your back end language (java/php or any other) to load the code into javascript and dynamically change it through there. I can provide you an example, but please be aware that it is a very gruesome process. IFrames can be a good option.

Anyways, here is a code example,

```
function viewPermit(permitId){
document.getElementById('permit-submenu').innerHTML ="";
var permitSubContent = "";
$.getJSON(
        "newAttendant.do",
        {"method":"getPermitDescription" ,"permitId": permitId},
        function(response){
            if(response.length>0){
                for(i = 0; i<response.length; i++){
                permitSubContent += '<div class="row">'
                    +'<h1>'+response[0].title+'</h1>'   
                    +'<p>Requested by: <span>'+response[0].requestedBy+'</span> | On: <span>'+response[0].requestedDate+'</span></p>';  
                    if(response[0].approvedBy != null) permitSubContent += '<p>Approved by: <span>'+response[0].approvedBy+'</span> | On: <span>'+response[0].approvedDate+'</span></p>';           
                    if(response[0].contractor != "") permitSubContent += '<p>Contractor: <span>'+response[0].contractor+'</span></p>'
                    +'<hr>';
                    if(response[0].description != "") permitSubContent += '<strong>Description:</strong>'   
                    +'<p>'+response[0].description+'</p>';
                    permitSubContent +='</div>';
                    }
                }

            document.getElementById('permit-submenu').innerHTML = permitSubContent;
            }
        );
```

}